# Distribute Apple Pay app through enterprise account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Enterprise accounts can't generate merchant id for Apple pay.
Is there any way to distribute apps that support Apple pay through an enterprise account for beta testers or the only way to do so is to remove Apple Pay from the project?

Comment: I was just about to ask this very same thing... We have all of our beta testing team running on an Enterprise account, and would need this to work there.

Comment: We still didn't find a proper solution. We'll most likely create a new target in XCode that does not include Apple Pay and distribute it through Enterprise account.

Comment: Any result? I've encountered with the same thing

Comment: No, still didn't find a solution. I doubt Apple will allow that, sounds too dangerous.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: Enterprise accounts are not intended for beta testing, they are intended for distribution of internal production apps. Use ad-hoc/TestFlight instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with those two solutions:

- When the need of Apple Pay is the highest, distribute with Apple Pay through App Store account with adhoc distribution profile.
- When the need for Enterprise distribution is the highest, distribute through the Enterprise account with adhoc distribution profile, and with Apple Pay Stubs https://github.com/stripe/ApplePayStubs from Stripe.

I go from one to the other depending on a pre-processor macro.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by duplicating the target. I turned the Apple Pay capability off in my target used for enterprise and left it on for my App Store Distribution. I also defined a macro so that Apple Pay is disabled on our enterprise builds. This will not allow us to test Apple Pay with our beta testers but still allows us to distribute builds to whichever users we're targeting without build failures.