# ApplePay - How to register

Tags: ios, applepay

Would like to know how to enable apple pay in the apple dev account to create a merchant ID.

When I reach https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/merchant/merchantCreate.action
it says, "The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible for this feature."

Would like to know the perquisites for this feature. I have enrolled for "iOS Developer Enterprise Program"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently register for an Apple Pay merchant identifier using an enterprise account - you'll need to use a regular account instead.

Comment: Thanks Ixt! Found this too; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197855/distribute-apple-pay-app-through-enterprise-account